# Add folder to git

Tags: git

I want to add a whole folder structure to git. The main folder (where i ran git init) contains a few files and a folder where all the sources are located. git init only added the files that are directly in this root folder, marking the sub-folder as submodule. I don't want it to be a submodule though. How can i add the whole structure to my git repo?

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   MySubfolder (modified content, untracked content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git add MySubfolder/*
fatal: Path 'MySubfolder/file1.py' is in submodule 'MySubfolder'
```

Comment: can't understand. won't `git add -A` work?

Comment: No, not if git assumes that the folder is a submodule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do in this case would be to start over. Copy your files to a temporary directory, delete your repository directory, run `git init` again, then copy them back. `git add` will work normally after that.